# How can I make it harder for players to hack game level data?

Tags: android, sql, algorithm, security, encryption

**Note:** this is in relation to android specifically, but the best answer might not be platform specific, hence the other tags.

Consider a game similar to angry birds: you have a bunch of levels. Each time you finish a level, the next level is available for play, but not before. How can I make it harder for players to hack my game files and unlock levels that shouldn't be available? Assume that progression data is stored locally.

**My thoughts:**

On android, all app files are stored in a folder that the user can only access if they have root access (by default, they never do, but it's usually very easy to get as long as you google a little). Right now, I am using an sqlite database that looks something like this:

```
LevelId = pk | UnlockStatus = int, 0 = locked, 1 = unlocked, 2 = completed with 1 star, ...
```

This is fine as long as the user doesn't have root or is not at all familiar with where app files are stored. If they have root however, this file is very easy to edit.

As far as  I can tell, angry birds stores its level data in a `.lua` file, at least according to its name. I can find no text file or db file that contains level info. Opening this `.lua` in a text editor displays nothing but gibberish. I haven't tried a hex editor.

Using an sql table is very convenient. Is there an easy way to store the progression data in the sql table such that the user will have a harder time making sense of it? Ideally, it should also not be too time-consuming to implement. Being an offline game, I don't care THAT much if the player hacks it or not, so I'm looking for the best quality - implementation time trade-off. Theoretical answers that yield a lot more implementation time for considerably more quality are also appreciated however.

Comment: how about encrypting data and then storing it... have not tried myself.. I think thats something possible...

Comment: As you've already mentioned: if a player wants to ruin it for themselves, why go to the trouble of trying to stop them?

Comment: It's already pretty hard to do this, and definitely out of reach for most of your players. Why bother making it harder?

Comment: @NickJohnson Most of all curiosity - I'm interested how it could be done. The method suggested is quite easy, so it wouldn't be that much trouble. Second, peer pressure. Most games I tried seem to do it, so I feel I'd be falling behind a little if I didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You best bet would be saving data using some sort of encryption. In android, SQLite doesn't offer encryption at database level. However, you may encrypt the values (records) in table and decrypt them after querying.

Another way could be saving your data as key/value pair in some sort of text file (example of .lua in angrybirds) in internal or external memory and perform encryption on the file contents. On the other hand, decrypt it at run-time and read your key/value pairs.

Tadaaa! problemo solved  :)

Comment: What would my encryption key be? Is it okay if I just hardcode some random string? Also, I would have to encrypt more than just the status value, since `encrypt(1)` would have the same value for all levels. Would encrypting the status code concatenated with the level number be good enough?

Comment: In one of my app, i use device's bluetooth-address (or you may try wifi mac-address) as encryption-key to encrypt data. Ooops, did i just announced my encryption logic? :p  Anyhow, with such key, your data decryption is bound to that particular device only which encrypts it. It depends on you how much data you want to encrypt. I would say, encrypt/decrypt all the settings wouldn't be a problem to handle.

Comment: You're absolutely right that if you want to decrypt the data seamlessly (without prompting the user for a password), you need to store a key somewhat and once someone finds out where you're getting that key from, they can recover it and decrypt the data (and re-encrypt modified data) themselves. You cannot really solve this problem, just get crafty with how you store/form the key to make things more difficult for your attacker to slow them down and, hopefully, make it take up enough time that it's not worth it to them anymore.

Comment: One more thing: if you use something device-specific like the bluetooth address, won't that make it impossible for users to backup their data when changing devices? I think a hardcoded key would work better in this case, but I could be wrong.

Comment: For games, i dont think people would bother about backing up its data. Anyhow, for backup purposes, i would suggest you to use **Android Backup Service** http://code.google.com/android/backup/index.html

Answer (score 1):

a simple method: **store differet level data for each player.**

*code less than 5 lines:*

```
//encrypt code:
save_level = "level_txt" + "#"+ md5("gamename" + "playername" + level_txt)

//decrypt code:
level_plaintxt, md5_level = save_level.split("#")
if (md5_level == md5("gamename" + "playername" + level_plaintxt))
  return level_plaintxt
```

Comment: What do you mean for each player? I only have one player since it's an offline game. Besides, if player `x` knows that `asdf` displays for a level he finished, he knows he has to add `asdf` to unlock the other levels, doesn't he?

Comment: Oh noes O(n) complexity! This will run slow if you have more then 50000 levels! Don't use hash when you really want to encrypt.

Comment: If you have that many levels you would use a bisection search. And you don't want to encrypt as the decryption key would have to be on the client, so would also be easily hackable.

Comment: @IVlad "for each player" means, diff player has diff data of same level. so, if player A hacks his level data out, he cant use his data for player B.

Comment: @sandis  Y, this is not best encrytion, but simple enough making hacking not too easy.  **first** md5 and other hash functions are fast enough for cpus as Arm.  **second** that for loop is bad, i optimize it down

Comment: fanflix: true, what you suggest does work. My only objection would be that encryption is a more flexible solution, since it does not constrain the way one saves the data @Kirkham: all data needed to hack the program will always be available on the client, no matter if we use hash or encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Hacking your data (game binaries/level-data/highscore-tables etc.) which is stored locally  on the device (or eventually remotely) will always be accessible (and decodable) by someone who really wants to and knows how to do it.

Each layer of security you add will only make it more difficult (and such take a longer time) for the hacker. Sometimes even adding an additional layer of security takes more time to implement on your side than for the hacker to understand it. (There are famous examples in computing history, one is the XBox IIRC).

*Security by obscurity* is what you try to do when encrypting the data in your case. This is not sufficient in the long term. Especially when you project meets big audience.